# Not A Statement Error in Recursive method

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I wrote this simple recursive method to check if a number is palindrome.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        String str = Integer.toString(x);
        if(str.length() <= 1){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            char first = str.charAt(0);
            char last = str.charAt(str.length()-1);

            if (first == last){
                int short = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
                return isPalindrome(short);
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
  }
```

However, I keep getting the compile error that this line 
`int short = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));` is not a statement. Can anyone see what the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: `short` is a keyword; you cannot use it as the name of a variable.

Comment: A good IDE shows keywords in a different color (e.g. blue in the code above), which should make it obvious that you cannot use that name. You are using an IDE, right?

Comment: @Andreas It was a question on leetcode so it doesn't show anything different.

Comment: @timeRocket Nothing is stopping you from writing the code in an IDE, gaining all the goodies of the IDE, and then copy/pasting the final code when done. Goodies: Color coding, code completion, javadoc, instant compile errors, debugging, etc. <-- All good, even when writing small leet programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the variable name- short, it is a java keyword.

```
if (first == last){
                return isPalindrome(Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, str.length()-1)));
            }
```